# php display search result title on url

Tags: php

I am creating PHP search form i have added search variable name to html form but not showing title on URL when i searched my URL display like this http://localhost/zblog/results/1/ i want to get like this URL http://localhost/zblog/results/1/xxxxxx

Here is my code

```
 <form action="<?php echo $url; ?>results/1/<?php $search;?>" method="post" name="search" id="searchthis" style="display:inline;">
<input id="search-box" name="search" size="40" type="text" placeholder="what are you looking for............"/>    
<input id="search-btn" value="search" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: `echo` just like with `$url`: `<?php echo $search;?>`

Comment: i added but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this via key listener in JavaScript

```
<script>
var myUrl = "<?php echo $url; ?>results/1/";
function updateAction(ele) {
    var txt = ele.value; //get the user input
    ele.parentElement.setAttribute("action",myUrl+txt);
}
</script>
```

```
<input onkeyup="updateAction(this);" id="search-box" name="search" size="40" type="text" placeholder="what are you looking for............"/>
```

Comment: Glad it helps you, If you feel that it helps you can you please mark this answer as accepted, Thanks

Comment: @sm Kevin - check [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 0):

your form is submitting via post method. you need to grab the search query from `$_POST['search']`, and assign it to the variable `$search`

```
<?php $search = $_POST['search'] ?>
<form action="<?php echo $url; ?>results/1/<?php $search;?>" method="post" name="search" id="searchthis" style="display:inline;">
<input id="search-box" name="search" size="40" type="text" placeholder="what are you looking for............"/>    
<input id="search-btn" value="search" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: i have added but display same results